# Add JavaScript variable to HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am having trouble in adding JavaScript variable in HTML tag as code is written below and i want reult as Hello world or u cansay that js var + html content

Html code :

```
<div class ="box" >user</div>
```

Javascript code :

```
 <script>
   var one = "Hello";
</script>
```

result should be like this =>Hello user

Comment: How could the result possibly be Hello user?

Comment: Strange that you feel "Hello" is the variable part of "Hello user".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `<span>` element and then use jQuery selector to set the html of that element.

Here is an example:

```
<div class = "box"><span class="span"></span>user</div>
    <script type="text\javascript">
        $(".box .span").html("Hello ");
    </script>
```

Comment: You'll probably hast to explan him what is jQuery, or try another solution using vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with javascript tags. However, you **can** modify your html using the DOM. Start with this code snippet:

```
<div class="box" id="my-box">user</div>
<script>
  document.getElementById('my-box').innerHTML = "Hello " + document.getElementById('my-box').innerHTML;
</script>
```

Remember that `script` tag load and evaluate javascript code, but does **not** replace it in your html body.

Also, you should start programming javascript [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/).

Answer (score 0):

This help you :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    
    </head>
     <body>
         <div class ="box" >user</div>
         <p id="result"></p>
         <script>
             var box = document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].innerHTML;
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello " + box;
         </script>
    </body>
</html>
```